# count how many months until Oct without using any thing but cout

Tags: c++, c++14

How to count the number of months from a given month to Oct without using any loop, statement or STL, but we can use `abs()`.

Example:

```
cin >> a; //given month
cout << yourCodeHere;
```

- Inp: 3 OutP: 7,
- Inp: 12 OutP: 10,
- Inp: 10 Outp: 0

My problem is I don't know how to do without using those if else statement.

Comment: Aksing homework related questions is fine. But you have to show what you have tried and explain what your problem is. StackOverflow is not a place to ask other people to do the work for you, but to help with specific problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of months to October of the following year, modulo 12.

```
cout << (22 - a) % 12;
```